# Interactive bokeh visualization - graph not updating

Tags: python, bokeh, interactive

I am a relative newbie to python and bokeh and trying to create an interactive bokeh plot of COVID incidence and deaths by country.
The code works perfectly without the Select tool, but when I rewrite it with the select tool I execute it, the graph does not update with a new selection.
I've obviously gone wrong in some fundamental issue, but I simply cannot figure this out. 
This code should run independently for anyone who is checking. I'm not sure if I have goofed up the update function, or if updating a variable does not work.

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, HoverTool, NumeralTickFormatter, DatetimeTickFormatter, Select
from bokeh.palettes import Category20b
from bokeh.layouts import layout

url_confirmed = 'https://data.humdata.org/hxlproxy/api/data-preview.csv?url=https%3A%2F%2Fraw.githubusercontent.com%2FCSSEGISandData%2FCOVID-19%2Fmaster%2Fcsse_covid_19_data%2Fcsse_covid_19_time_series%2Ftime_series_covid19_confirmed_global.csv&filename=time_series_covid19_confirmed_global.csv'
url_deaths = 'https://data.humdata.org/hxlproxy/api/data-preview.csv?url=https%3A%2F%2Fraw.githubusercontent.com%2FCSSEGISandData%2FCOVID-19%2Fmaster%2Fcsse_covid_19_data%2Fcsse_covid_19_time_series%2Ftime_series_covid19_deaths_global.csv&filename=time_series_covid19_deaths_global.csv'


covid_confirmed = pd.read_csv(url_confirmed)
covid_confirmed_grp = covid_confirmed.groupby('Country/Region').sum()
covid_deaths = pd.read_csv(url_deaths)
covid_deaths_grp = covid_deaths.groupby('Country/Region').sum()


covid_confirmed_dates = covid_confirmed_grp.drop(columns = ['Lat', 'Long'])
covid_confirmed_dates = covid_confirmed_dates.transpose()
covid_confirmed_dates = covid_confirmed_dates.reset_index()
covid_confirmed_dates = covid_confirmed_dates.rename(columns = {'index':'date'})
covid_confirmed_dates['date'] = pd.to_datetime(covid_confirmed_dates['date'])


covid_deaths_dates = covid_deaths_grp.drop(columns = ['Lat', 'Long'])
covid_deaths_dates = covid_deaths_dates.transpose()
covid_deaths_dates = covid_deaths_dates.reset_index()
covid_deaths_dates = covid_deaths_dates.rename(columns = {'index':'date'})
covid_deaths_dates['date'] = pd.to_datetime(covid_deaths_dates['date'])


countrylist = covid_confirmed_dates.columns.tolist()
countrylist.remove('date')

# reset the output so that the file size does not increase
#bokeh.io.reset_output()

source_confirmed = ColumnDataSource(covid_confirmed_dates)
source_deaths = ColumnDataSource(covid_deaths_dates)
countrylist = ['India','US', 'Spain', "Italy", "Germany", "United Kingdom", 
               "France", "China", "Iran", "Turkey", "Belgium", 
               "Brazil", "Canada", "Netherlands", "Switzerland"]
mypallette = Category20b[20]
country = 'India'

# name the output file
output_file('covid_confirmed_deaths.html')

def update_country(attr,old,new):
    global country
    country = select.value

# define the figure variable
f = figure(plot_width=800, plot_height=500, x_axis_type="datetime")

f.xaxis.axis_label = "Date"
f.yaxis.axis_label = "Cases"
f.title.text = 'COVID19 Cases'

f.line(x = 'date', y = country, color='red', alpha=1, source = source_confirmed, line_width = 3, name = country, legend_label=country)

f.legend.location = "top_left"
f.legend.click_policy="hide"
f.legend.title = 'Tap to toggle on/off'
f.yaxis[0].formatter = NumeralTickFormatter(format="0,000,000")
f.xaxis[0].formatter = DatetimeTickFormatter(days="%d/%m")
hover = HoverTool(
    tooltips = [
        ("country", "$name"),
        ("date", "@date{%d/%m}"),
        ("cases", "$y{0,000,000}")
    ],
    formatters={
        '@date': 'datetime',
        },
    )
f.add_tools(hover)

# define the figure variable
g = figure(plot_width=800, plot_height=500, x_axis_type="datetime")

g.xaxis.axis_label = "Date"
g.yaxis.axis_label = "Deaths"
g.title.text = 'COVID19 Deaths'

g.line(x = 'date', y = country, color='blue', alpha=1, source = source_deaths, line_width = 3, name = country, legend_label=country)

g.legend.location = "top_left"
g.legend.click_policy="hide"
g.legend.title = 'Tap to toggle on/off'
g.yaxis[0].formatter = NumeralTickFormatter(format="0,000,000")
g.xaxis[0].formatter = DatetimeTickFormatter(days="%d/%m")
hover = HoverTool(
    tooltips = [
        ("country", "$name"),
        ("date", "@date{%d/%m}"),
        ("cases", "$y{0,000,000}")
    ],
    formatters={
        '@date': 'datetime',
        },
    )
g.add_tools(hover)

countrylist1 = [('India', 'India'),('US','US'), ('Spain', 'Spain'), 
               ('Italy', 'Italy'), ('Germany', 'Germany'), ('United Kingdom', 'United Kingdom'), 
               ('France', 'France'), ('China', 'China'), ('Iran', 'Iran'),('Turkey', 'Turkey'), ('Belgium', 'Belgium'),
               ('Brazil', 'Brazil'), ('Canada', 'Canada'), ('Netherlands', 'Netherlands'), ('Switzerland', 'Switzerland')]
select = Select(title="Select Country:", value="India", options=countrylist1)
select.on_change("value", update_country)

lay_out=layout([[select]])
curdoc().add_root(lay_out)
curdoc().add_root(f)
curdoc().add_root(g)
```

Answer (score 0):

In order for Bokeh to know about the changes that you've made, you have to apply those changes to Bokeh models. Most of the time it's a data source, but it can be any other model. E.g. when you call `f.line()`, it returns an instance of `GlyphRenderer`. To change its `y` property, you can use `renderer.glyph.y = select.value`. Same for `name`.

It's much harder to do for the `legend_label` though. The thing is, it's not an attribute but just a convenient way to create an instance of the `Legend` model and setup all its machinery for you automatically. In order to change the legend label, you will have to dig into the way legends work and change the right attribute of the right model.

Comment: Thanks. So should I use: `f.line.glyph.y = select.value` in the update function - or how should I use this? I am not sure if f.line has an attribute glyph.

Comment: No, not `f.line.something`. Rather `renderer = f.line(...); renderer.glyph.y = ...`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked with `renderer = f.line(...)` and then in the update function, using `renderer.glyph.y = select.value` and `renderer.name = select.value`. I had to get rid of the legend, which was fine because I was plotting only one country at a time. I will try a new version where I will update the ColumnDataSource.